# MYSQL inventory slots (add item to next slot free)

Tags: mysql

```
  $slt = mysql_query("select Slot, ItemId, UserId, max(Slot) Slot
  from useritems
  group by UserId");    

  while ($sloot = mysql_fetch_assoc($slt))
{
 Echo "<br>Items with biggest slots are: " . $sloot['ItemId'] . " from user " . $sloot['UserId']. "- in slot-". $sloot['Slot'];
}
```

This is the table

```
Idi Quantity    ItemId  UserId  Slot    ExpirationDate
```

Outputs the smallest Slots...Why?

1.I want to show me the biggest inventory slot from each user, so when i add a new item to his inventory i can add on next slot..From example user Paul has 5 items that ocupies slots 1,2,3,4,5 and the next item will be on slot 6.

2.When a user moves his items on slots 1,2,4,5,6 the next item added will be on slot 3

I did a lot of search but i can't find out myself:) PS:The game wich i`m making it`s just for fun..but maybe someday will be a great game:) (dreams,dreams :)) )

EDIT:

SQLFIDDLE is very good thank you:) it's exactly what i need to learn some SQL 
Table useritems

[useritems Table IMAGE](http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/4097/useritems.png) 
[items Table](http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/9796/itemstable.png)

My Echo shows me that:

```
Id = 1 and it should be 3; user=4(good); slot=4(good)
Id = 1 and it should be 2; user=5(good); slot=2(good)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!:) i just forgot to select data where UserId=my_id  but it shows me the corect output only if the respective user has more than 3 items...

```
$slt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM useritems WHERE Slot=(select max(Slot) from useritems) and UserId='$id'");
```

and `$id = $_SESSION['id'];`

```
$slt = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM `useritems` 
    WHERE UserId='$id' AND Slot=(select max(Slot) 
    from useritems where UserId='$id')
");`
```

EDIT2:I found the best way with all i was searching but i don`t  knwo how to use WHERE clause userId='$id'

```
$slt2 = mysql_query("select l.Slot + 1 as start
    from useritems as l
    left outer join useritems as r on l.Slot + 1 = r.Slot
    where r.Slot is null and l.UserId=4;
") or die(mysql_error());   `
```

With this query the item should be placed on Slot 2(wich is missing) but it`s dysplays Slot 6 (wich is the highest for the user with UserId=4)

Finally this is the last edit

```
$slt2 = mysql_query("SELECT  Slot + 1 as start
   FROM    useritems mo
   WHERE   NOT EXISTS
   (
       SELECT  NULL
       FROM    useritems mi 
       WHERE   mi.Slot = mo.Slot + 1 AND mi.UserId = '$id'  
   )ORDER BY Slot LIMIT 1
") or die(mysql_error());   `
```

This is what i was searching.:X

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
select userid, itemid, max(slot) from useritems where itemid is not null and quantity>0
group by userid, itemid
```

It'd be easier to help you if you share your table script with some data.

You can use: http://sqlfiddle.com/

EDIT:

What about this? Itemid=0 means the slot is free? So min(slot) will be the first free slot by user.

```
select userid, min(slot) from useritems where itemid=0 group by userid
```

Comment: why it shows me the Item's id with the smallest Slot and then it Shows the correct Slot?[http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/3521/resultm.png](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/3521/resultm.png)

Comment: `$slt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM useritems WHERE Slot=(select max(Slot) from useritems)"); `     This is closer but it shows me just 1 user with the highest ocupied Slot

Comment: no...slots are beteen 1 and 50, but if i delete the item from slot 2 it remains empty....and if there are 32 slots completed with slot 2 empty, the next ocupied slot will be 33 . i did a lot o searching with how to find gaps and etc but none worked...